# Put value into map if not null

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Does Java have something like

```
map.putIfValueNotNull(key, value)
```

So I can put value in the map only if it`s not null without explicit checking.

Comment: That is a very poor naming choice ,`putIfValueNotNull(...)` would be more fitting. But no, the [`Map` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) does not specify such a method.

Comment: You can create your own method from an extended map, but it's really only an extra if statement so the return is a more complex class for a single line's savings.

Comment: @Compass or you simply extend the interface with a default implementation for this method =)

Comment: Right your own Class over java.util.HashMap and define such methods using appropriate suppose like @NotNull Annotation.

Comment: @ArifMustafa `@NotNull` is just an annotation and not necessarily checked. It would be better to use something like [`Objects.requireNonNull(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T))

Comment: @Turing85 Exactly, that's why I used the term **suppose like** inside my comment, are we good now?

Comment: @ArifMustafa of course we are - we were before as well ;)

Answer (score 15):

In such a case, I would just use `Optional`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(value).ifPresent(v -> map.put(key, v));
```

Formally, this doesn't meet the requirement of explicit checking absence, but it is still quite short and clean, and no operation is performed with map if the value is `null`.

Comment: It looks quite nice, I just wanted to put elements in the map only if its value is not null
Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I know that `org.apache.commons.collections4.MapUtils` contains method `safeAddToMap()`, but if `value` is `null`, it adds `empty string` which is not what you want.

I do not like variant, to override `HashMap` to implement new method, because in this case you do not have it for other implementations: `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap` or else.

I do not know about that this function exists in some availabe library, like `Apache` or similar.

Therefore, in my projects, I have to implement it myself:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> addNotNull(Map<K, V> map, K key, V value) {
    if(value != null)
        map.put(key, value);

    return map;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to return `map`. The `map` will be changed or not after this method because you use the `pass-by-value` reference.

Comment: @MykolaShorobura I know it. This is just to provide a chain. Like builder.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `computeIfAbsent()` function which checks if the key is already in the map. If it is there it doesn't do anything.
If the key is not present then it checks if the calculated value is null and puts into the map it if it is not.

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, val -> value);
```

Be careful, `putIfAbsent` puts null values into the map.

Comment: I think what he is going for is not putting anything in the map if it is null.

Comment: This doesn't fulfil OP's requirements. Your code doesn't behave like `put` when the passed value is not null, i.e. it doesn't overwrite values

Answer (score 4):

I tried the following and it seems to work.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
String object1 = "blah";
String object2 = null;
map.compute("key1", (k, v) -> object1);
map.compute("key2", (k, v) -> object2);

System.out.println(map);
```

I don't know if there are performance or other considerations that would make this way undesirable. It looks pretty clean to me. If `object1` or `object2` is null, then they don't end up in the map. When I run this I get the following result.

```
{key1=blah}
```

Note that if a value with the same key is already in the map, it will be replaced.

Comment: A small clarification: if a null value is being put for an existing key by calling Map#compute, that key is removed from the map

Comment: This doesn't fulfil OP's requirements because, if the passed value is null and there already exists an entry with the same key, it deletes the entry from the map. `put` never removes any entry

Answer (score 2):

As per the java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null.

A simple example to put:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("1", "ONE");
    map.put("2", null);

    map.computeIfAbsent("3", val -> "THREE");
    map.computeIfAbsent("4", val -> null);

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

The output of this would be -

```
{1=ONE, 2=null, 3=THREE}
```

It is clear that the output does not contain the null values if added via computeIfAbsent method, while they are present if added by normal put method.

Comment: isn't that exactly HDCase's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49150371/85421) ? and what if I already have a mapping for the given key e.g. `map.put("3" "to do")` - `computeIfAbsent("3", "THREE")` will not replace it

Comment: This doesn't fulfil OP's requirements. Your code doesn't behave like `put` when the passed value is not null, i.e. it doesn't overwrite values

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth just filtering the resulting map:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
   .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
   .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))
```

however, the memory consumption and GC load are higher. So I would use this for the sake of readability if the map is small.